# I can't receive all server responses

Tags: android, bufferedinputstream, surfaceflinger, bufferqueue

In my Android app I'm connected to a server and keep receiving data from it when the app is on run-time, every thing was working so fine, but lately without any code changes, my app keep losing a big amounts of data and not receiving it from the server, and instead I'm getting a many of the following log messages which centered around `BufferQueue` and `SurfaceFlinger`:

```
04-27 11:13:09.411: I/SurfaceTextureClient(5050): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x541b0840) fps:30.37, dur:1020.68, max:48.91, min:17.21
04-27 11:13:09.412: I/BufferQueue(139): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41c90720,api:1) [queue] fps:30.36, dur:1021.12, max:48.90, min:17.21
04-27 11:13:09.425: I/BufferQueue(139): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41c90720,api:1) [release] fps:30.38, dur:1020.25, max:50.17, min:16.71
04-27 11:13:09.425: I/SurfaceFlinger(139): [SurfaceFlinger] fps:30.384575,dur:1020.25,max:50.17,min:16.72
04-27 11:13:10.055: D/StateMachine(510): handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
04-27 11:13:10.055: D/StateMachine(510): processMsg: ConnectedState
04-27 11:13:10.056: D/WifiStateMachine(510): ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-4ms arg1=21 target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41d24e10} }
04-27 11:13:10.056: D/StateMachine(510): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
04-27 11:13:10.057: D/WifiStateMachine(510): L2ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-5ms arg1=21 target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41d24e10} }
04-27 11:13:10.058: D/WifiNative-wlan0(510): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
04-27 11:13:10.058: D/WifiCommon(510): [wlan0] SET "SIGNAL_POLL"
04-27 11:13:10.059: D/wpa_supplicant(698): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
04-27 11:13:10.059: D/wpa_supplicant(698): wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
04-27 11:13:10.062: D/wpa_supplicant(698): nl80211: survey data missing!
04-27 11:13:10.064: I/WifiStateMachine(510): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative, newRssi:-53, newLinkSpeed:54
04-27 11:13:10.066: V/ActivityManager(510): Broadcast sticky: Intent { act=android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } ordered=false userid=-1
04-27 11:13:10.067: D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine(510): RSSI current: 3 new: -53, 4
04-27 11:13:10.068: D/StateMachine(510): handleMessage: X
04-27 11:13:10.414: I/SurfaceTextureClient(5050): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x541b0840) fps:29.91, dur:1003.06, max:36.29, min:30.43
04-27 11:13:10.414: I/BufferQueue(139): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41c90720,api:1) [queue] fps:29.92, dur:1002.56, max:36.34, min:30.44
04-27 11:13:10.429: I/BufferQueue(139): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41c90720,api:1) [release] fps:29.89, dur:1003.56, max:33.66, min:33.30
04-27 11:13:10.429: I/SurfaceFlinger(139): [SurfaceFlinger] fps:29.893894,dur:1003.55,max:33.72,min:33.29
04-27 11:13:10.787: V/ActivityManager(510): Broadcast sticky: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIG_STR flg=0x10 (has extras) } ordered=false userid=-1
04-27 11:13:10.790: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(660): [BT][HFG] [API] mStateReceiver.onReceive(android.intent.action.SIG_STR)
04-27 11:13:10.790: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(660): [BT][HFG] [API] mHandler.handleMessage(10)
04-27 11:13:10.796: D/ADB_SERVICES(212): adb fdevent_process list (11) (21) 
04-27 11:13:11.134: I/System.out(5050): PARSED
04-27 11:13:11.417: I/SurfaceTextureClient(5050): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x541b0840) fps:29.90, dur:1003.48, max:34.16, min:32.70
04-27 11:13:11.418: I/BufferQueue(139): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41c90720,api:1) [queue] fps:29.90, dur:1003.48, max:34.18, min:32.68
04-27 11:13:11.432: I/BufferQueue(139): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41c90720,api:1) [release] fps:29.89, dur:1003.56, max:33.54, min:33.39
04-27 11:13:11.432: I/SurfaceFlinger(139): [SurfaceFlinger] fps:29.893744,dur:1003.55,max:33.58,min:33.37
04-27 11:13:13.070: D/StateMachine(510): handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
04-27 11:13:13.070: D/StateMachine(510): processMsg: ConnectedState
04-27 11:13:13.071: D/WifiStateMachine(510): ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-3ms arg1=21 target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41d24e10} }
04-27 11:13:13.071: D/StateMachine(510): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
04-27 11:13:13.072: D/WifiStateMachine(510): L2ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-4ms arg1=21 target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41d24e10} }
04-27 11:13:13.072: D/WifiNative-wlan0(510): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
04-27 11:13:13.073: D/WifiCommon(510): [wlan0] SET "SIGNAL_POLL"
04-27 11:13:13.073: D/wpa_supplicant(698): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
04-27 11:13:13.073: D/wpa_supplicant(698): wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
04-27 11:13:13.090: D/wpa_supplicant(698): nl80211: survey data missing!
04-27 11:13:13.091: I/WifiStateMachine(510): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative, newRssi:-53, newLinkSpeed:54
04-27 11:13:13.091: D/StateMachine(510): handleMessage: X
04-27 11:13:13.325: D/Settings/BW(4073): ReadCodeTask:file size: 4096
```

Comment: What kind of server? Protocol? What kind of client?

Comment: @greenapps it's our own server and it exists within the same network, and I'm using regular java socket programming with `BufferedReader` to receive responses

Comment: `What kind of server? Protocol? `. Http?

Comment: @greenapps in fact, I found the issue but I don't know the reason, the `BufferedReader` was declared as `static` for some purpose, and when removing static identifier the code worked perfectly, in fact it was accessed by a single object which is inside a single thread, so I can't find any reason for that behaviour

Comment: Those look like debug messages added by an OEM. They don't appear to indicate any sort of error or warning. In any event, SurfaceFlinger is the system graphics compositor, and is not related to your app's network activity.

Comment: @fadden yea you are right, that's what I discovered